# AWS hosted application need autosuggest & wild card search feature

Tags: amazon-web-services

I 'm not sure if this is the correct platform to ask architecture related question, actually I have a webapplication developed in nodejs & typescript hosted in AWS, and the backend is mongodb and my requirement is to include a search box with wild card & auto suggest search functionality so when I start typing on the text box, it will autosuggest just like we do in google search, so how would I achieve this, querying everytime to mongodb will be kind of slow and if 100's of user start doing that, then my application might start dangling so need your suggestion.

Not tried as this more of architecture help required

Not tried as this more of architecture help required

Comment: How are you hosting the nodejs application in Aws?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, It's in ECS, it's more of node js, typescript & html app

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very detailed answer but may point you in a direction.

I just built something similar using AWS Lambda, ElasticSearch and API Gateway.
ElasticSearch is great for text searches but needs to be populated with indexed data.

If your dataset is changing, you will have to remember about updating ElasticSearch.
API Gateway routes requests from HTTP to Lambda, of which there are two:
one for analysing data in my data warehouse and producing indices for ElasticSearch, the other for doing the actual search and returning results.

Comment: Thanks, I did this in Azure however I 'm little confused over here, how you have populated data in elastic search initially? I assume from your comments, you have  used API gateway to check whether the data is synced right ? if not please comment, a more detailed insight would be useful, a sample code will do if you don't mind.

Comment: any help on this ?